# ARM deployment fails with incorrect DSC extension template error

Tags: azure, deployment

I have ARM deployment template, which contains VM resource with DSC extension

```
"resources": [
        {
          "name": "Microsoft.Powershell.DSC",
          "type": "extensions",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', parameters('appVMName'))]"
          ],
          "tags": {
            "displayName": "appDSC"
          },
          "properties": {
            "publisher": "Microsoft.Powershell",
            "type": "DSC",
            "typeHandlerVersion": "2.9",
            "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
            "forceUpdateTag": "[parameters('appDSCUpdateTagVersion')]",
                    "settings": {
                        "configuration": {
                            "url": "[parameters('dscArchiveUrl')]",
                            "script": "appDSC.ps1",
                            "function": "Main"
                        },
                    "configurationArguments": {
                        "nodeName": "[parameters('appVMName')]",
                        "webDeployPackage": "[parameters('appWebPackage')]",
                        "backgroundServicePackage": "[parameters('backgroundServicePackage')]"
                    }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
```

I managed to make this work for the first time I executed it, but now it responds with error:

```
15:37:17 - Resource Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines 'Unique-InApp' failed with message '{
  "status": "Failed",
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
    "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "VMExtensionProvisioningError",
        "message": "VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'Microsoft.Powershell.DSC'. Error message: \"The
 DSC Extension received an incorrect input: Configuration.url requires that configuration.script is specified.\nPlease c
orrect the input and retry executing the extension.\"."
      }
    ]
  }
}'
```

As you can see, I obviously put `script` to `configuration`, but for some reason it is not recognized by ARM deployment script.
I suppose, this is just wrong error message and I have different problem, but without proper diagnostic information I am not able to understand it.
So what is the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: any reason why you are using version 2.9? latets is 2.22...have you tried uninstalling the extension and then re-deploying?

Comment: it helped, thank you

Comment: it couldn't possibly help, there's the autoupgrademinorversion flag set to true @Kiran

Comment: true that the minor version wud have upgraded at runtime...the dsc extension format changed some time ago...havent seen many ppl using the new format...i am not sure if a  recent version of the api is required for azure to understand the new format...also if an old version was installed dont htink that it wud automatically be upgraded unless u re-install the extension...@4c74356b41

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/dsc-extension-iis-server-windows-vm/azuredeploy.json) example and at the [schema](http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-08-01/Microsoft.Compute.json#/resourceDefinitions/virtualMachines) seems like you are doing it wrong.

I don't see `script` or `function` properties for DSC extension, instead I see `configurationFunction` property, which supposedly takes a value similar to this:

```
ContosoWebsite.ps1\\ContosoWebsite
```

Second slash is used to escape the first one ;)

Comment: Problem is still actual with the same error, even after I've changed my template:
`"modulesUrl": "[parameters('dscArchiveUrl')]"`
`"configurationFunction": "appDSC.ps1\\Main"`

Comment: i suggest you take existing quickstart template I've linked and test your dsc extension with it.

Comment: I dont need this quickstart template to work, I need to deploy my app with my template. Whatever result this quickstart produces, it wont help me with my problem.

Comment: well, godspeed.

Comment: @Sovent Have you found a solution? I am getting the same problem

Comment: We've reworked this template several times since I've posted that question, but we've ended up with almost no differences in this block. We've just moved it from "resources" to "extensions" of our virtual machine scale set configuration